# Mathematical calculation using for loop in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
df= 

    Time                  x          y
0   2018-09-13 01:17:00  5.0        0.0
1   2018-09-13 02:17:00  9.0        0.0
2   2018-09-13 03:17:00  2.0        1.0
3   2018-09-13 04:17:00  1.0        0.0
```

.......
I want to iterate through this whole dataframe and calculate a new variable z.
The value of z would be `z= z[prev]+ x-y`

for example,  the final output would be

```
Time                         z
0   2018-09-13 01:17:00      5    #[0+5-0]
1   2018-09-13 02:17:00      14   #[5+9-0]
2   2018-09-13 03:17:00      15   #[14+2-1]
3   2018-09-13 04:17:00      16   #[15+1-0]
```

.....

I am finding it difficult to iterate over the time series data.

I have tried the following but it is not working.

```
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    z=0
    row['z']=row['z']+row['x']-row['y']

print[z]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case do [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html)

```
df['new'] = df.x.sub(df.y).cumsum()
Out[410]: 
0  2018-09-13     5.0
1  2018-09-13    14.0
2  2018-09-13    15.0
3  2018-09-13    16.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use indices

```
z = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    if i == 0:
        z.append(df.loc[i]['x'] - df.loc[i]['y'])
    else:
        z.append(z[i-1] + df.loc[i]['x'] - df.loc[i]['y'])

df['z'] = z
```

Comment: Awesome! This will help me to understand the concept of for loop!